# MySQL Fulltextsearch with umlauts

Tags: mysql

Why shows me MySQL if i fire the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM fast.zusammen where match(NAMEN) against('+stefan* +kohl*' in boolean mode);
```

as result this one:

FirstName: Stefan
LastName: **Köhler**

Answer (score 0):

It finds that result because + means AND, and the result matches both constraints.

Details of this feature are here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: But i mean the 'ö'. Why does mysql search for them...is a completely other name

Comment: That's because of collation. You probably need to set your collation to utf8_swedish_ci more details are here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html